# Flex 4 text rendering in s:RichEditableText component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm curious to see if anyone can shed some light on some strange text rendering behavior in the Spark RichEditableText component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

creationComplete="handleApplicationCreationComplete()"
>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;

        private static const DATA:Array =
        [
            "First sentence. This is a test of text rendering. How's it look?",
            "Let's see if this actually works correctly.",
            "Add some variety with the <b>bold</b> tag...",
            "Throw in a <a href='http://www.example.com'>link</a> as well!",
            "Well?! Does it work as expected? I think not..."
        ];

        private var currentIdx:int;

        protected function handleNextClick():void
        {
            currentIdx++;
            if(currentIdx >= DATA.length)
                currentIdx = 0;
            display(currentIdx);
        }

        protected function handleApplicationCreationComplete():void
        {
            currentIdx = 0;
            display(currentIdx);
        }

        private function display(idx:int):void
        {
            contentDisplay.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(DATA[idx], TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout />
</s:layout>

<s:VGroup width="100">
    <s:RichEditableText id="contentDisplay"
        width="100%"
        enabled="false" mouseEnabled="false"
        editable="false" focusEnabled="false"
    />
</s:VGroup>
<s:Button label="Next" click="handleNextClick()" />
</s:Application>
```

The above application simply navigates through the five sentences in the `DATA` array (every time the `Next` button is pressed). For whatever reason, `RichEditableText` component doesn't completely reset its view (by clearing the previous text) before setting new content. From what I can gather, this faulty rendering is somehow based on the combination of line count and relative width. I also discovered that if I set the `width` property of the `RichEditableText` component to an absolute value (say, `100`) as opposed to relative (percentage, `100%`) the text is rendered correctly.

As far as I can see, this behavior is unintended and is, in fact, a bug.

[image: Text on startup]

[image: Text after "next" is clicked]

[image: Text after "next" is clicked again]

Comment: I believe this is working correctly for me.  Or at least I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong.  Can you post a screenshot of the bad behavior you are seeing?  What SDK version are you using?

Comment: Hadn't found any wierd behavior of the code as well. I would also check flash player version.

Comment: I'm using Flex SDK 4.1 and according to Adobe's website my Flashplayer version is 10,1,102,64. I doubt it has anything to do with the player version though. I also added screenshots

Comment: I wish to add that I'm getting the same behaviour with RichEditableText. I've set the text box width to 100% and heightInLines to NaN. The first line is updated, but subsequent lines contain the old text. I'm using SDK 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no solution, it's a bug in the framework...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the 4.1 SDK. To work around this issue you can clear the RTE and then update it on the subsiquent frame.

```
callLater(function workAround(richEditableText:RichEditableText, updateText:String):void
{
    richEditableText.text = updateText;
}
, [ myRichEditableTextComponent, myNewMessageText ]);
```

Just place this code where you were previously updating the RET and pass through the component and the new text. This should work the same if you are using a text flow, just replace text and the text string with the flow.